# Firefox won't open any pages, everything else does

Tags: firefox

I am using Windows 10 (Home 22H2) with the latest version of Firefox (11.0.1 64-bit) and, as the title says, Firefox throws an error like this every time I try to open a page while everything else works like Chrome, Edge and when I ping via command prompt I get replies and other applications.

> "We can’t connect to the server at m.imdb.com."

I  think it's a system-wide problem but I can't figure out where. I was under the impression that it's a DNS problem but it doesn't even open IP addresses like 192.168.1.1 and it doesn't open instantly, no matter it's Google.com or my router IP, instant error message.

I tried everything I could find which are:

- Refresh, clean re-install with deleting profile directory
- clearing cache and data
- Toggling these in about:config: network.http.http3.enabled, network.dns.disableIPv6, network.dns.disablePrefetch
- Enabling/disabling my adapter
- Running a couple commands:
  ipconfig /flushdns
  ipconfig /registerdns
  ipconfig /release
  ipconfig /renew

  netsh int ip reset resetlog.txt
  netsh winsock reset catalog
  netsh int ipv4 reset reset.log
  netsh int ipv6 reset reset.log
- Setting proxy to None
- Restarting with Troubleshoot Mode (add-ons disabled)
- Removing Firefox entry from Windows Firewall. (I haven't installed any Firewall and Anti-Virus)
- WIndows's Network Reset
- Rebooting machine and router

I'm sure there are more, these are all I can remember now.

This happened some months ago but can't seem to remember how I fixed it.

The only way it opens sites is with a VPN that sets a system proxy and setting Firefox's proxy to "Use System Proxy Settings".

Comment: `Removing Firefox entry from Windows Firewall` what is odd about this statement is that there was a firefox entry to begin with!

Comment: Did you mean Firefox 110.0.1 instead?

Comment: I meant there are 3 Firefox entries in Windows Defender Firewall, two for Domains, one TCP and one UDP and another for Private profile. (First two don't have icons but last one has a green icon)

Comment: See https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/configure-windows-firewall-allow-firefox-access .

Comment: Did not fix it.